# if $\tan(\cot(x))=\cot(\tan(x))$ find $\sin(2x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> If $\tan(\cot(x))=\cot(\tan(x))$, find $\sin(2x)$.

so to start

$\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\cot \left(x\right)\right)=\cot\left(\tan\left(x\right)\right)$

or $\frac{\pi}{2}=\tan\left(x\right)+\frac{1}{\tan\left(x\right)}$

which is $\frac{\sec^2\left(x\right)}{1+\tan\left(x\right)}$

now using the sin(2x) formula that should give $\frac{4}{\pi}$

however, this is wrong

why is it wrong?

Comment: What is the correct answer? And aren't you forgetting $n\pi$

Comment: $\frac{4π}{41}$

Answer (score 2):

Here is the mistake.

$\cot A = \cot B \nRightarrow A = B$. We have :

$\cot A = \cot B \implies \tan A = \tan B \implies \sin ({A - B}) = 0 \implies A - B = n\pi$.

The second implication in the above line is proved by observing that $\tan A - \tan B = 0$ and simplifying further using sin and cos.

Answer (score 2):

You got the first line right, but since cot(x) is a periodic function with cycle $π$ then $\cot(a) =\cot(b)$ implies that $a=b+nπ$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ so
$$\tan(\cot(x))=\cot(tan(x))$$ $$\tan(π/2-\tan(x)) =\tan(\cot(x)) $$ $$π/2-\cot(x)+nπ=\tan(x) $$ $$π/2+nπ=tan(x) +\cot(x)$$ $$\frac{2nπ+π}{2}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}+\frac{cos^2(x)}{\cos(x)\sin(x)}$$
$$\frac{π}{2}(2n+1)=\frac{1}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}$$
$$\frac{π}{4}(2n+1)=\frac{1}{2\sin(x)cos(x)}$$
$$\frac{4}{π(2n+1)}=sin(2x)$$